# DQN, TF, nested spcaes.Dict : How to deal with variable size observation space?

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, dqn

I am very new to RL and DQN. And trying to code an agent for my problem statement. I am using Replay Buffer concept and trying to learn to code this agent manually. My observation space is a Dictionary with Tuple of Nested dict. As below.

```
    self.observation_space = spaces.Dict({
        "elem_1": spaces.Discrete(64),
        "elem_2": spaces.Box(low=0, high=100, shape=(1,), dtype=np.float32),
        "elem_3": spaces.Tuple((
            spaces.Dict({
                "prop_1": spaces.Discrete(100),
                "prop_2": spaces.Discrete(10),
                "prop_3": spaces.Discrete(4),
                "prop_4": spaces.Discrete(4),
            }),)*100
        ),
        "elem_4": spaces.Discrete(32)
    })
```

Now, in my epsilon_greedy_action_selection() function, I am trying to pass on an observation to this model. I have tried many things to flatten my observation but it fails for same reasons that I am unable to fix. Crux of the problem is, as I understand, the observation is not in an acceptable format. Can some one kindly help me "flatten" it (if that's the right term to go with). My function is as below :

```
def epsilon_greedy_action_selection(self, model, epsilon, observation):
    """
    All below lines that are commented is what I have tired and got no where.
    """
    logger.info("OBSERVATION RECEIVED : {}".format(len(observation)))
    type = None
    if np.random.random() > epsilon:
        prediction = model.predict(observation)
        action = np.argmax(prediction)
        type = "IF"
    
    else:
        action = random.sample(range(self.action_space.n), 1)[0]
        type = "ELSE"
    
    logger.info(f"Returning action as {action} from {type}")
    return action
```

The error is see is as below.

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'dict'> containing {"<class 'str'>"} keys and {"<class 'str'>", "(<class 'list'> containing values of types set())", "<class 'int'>"} values), <class 'NoneType'>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. I just need to be nudged in the direction where I can see what is being done wrong here or how to remodel my observation space/code.

Answer (score 1):

Took me whole month to crack this. It felt as if there is no one to answer this question.

1. YES : Dictionary observation space for a NON-GAMIN scenario (complex, nested dictionary spaces) are a legal thing. Don't worry!
2. Issue with my project was caused by Point#1. Since dictionary space was complex and nested, I was unable to visualize the overall flow. So here is how it goes.
3. You need to define your Dict flatten method. You can choose

   > gym.spaces.utils.flatten_space(self.observation_space)
   > # or define your own. Premise is to make sure that if a dict is say as like observation = {"a": 1, "b" : [{"c": 1, "d": 1}, {"c": 2,
   > "d": 1}]

   Output should be a 1D array [1, 1, 1, 2, 1] something similar.
4. Use the same function to flatten the observation that comes out when using the step function (next_state) or reset_state()
5. When using the Keras DQN, the same function can be shifted to a MyProcessor() and it should be passed as a constructor in the dqn.compile command as argument to processor. like so :

   dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, nb_actions=nb_actions, policy=policy, memory=memory, processor=MyProcessor(), nb_steps_warmup=30, gamma=.99, target_model_update=100, train_interval=4)
6. The MyProcessor class should also define 2 function :

   1. def process_observation(self, observation):
   2. def process_state_batch(self, batch):

Let me know if you face the same issue and I can try to help you!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to convert Numpy Arrays to Tensors using the example here before passing- https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/numpy

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking time to respond. I tried that but the real issue was something else. It took me whole month to figure that out. I will be answering my question in the comment below.